# .NET Framework version in Application Pools of IIS 7 on windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, .net, application-pools

I have web service on IIS 7 on Windows 2008.
This web service must dlls of .NET Framework 3.5 (I have error about System.Linq using when I try to browse the web site)

The only place I found where it is possible to change .NET Framework version is application pools management, but The only two options I have are: no management code and .NET Framework 2.
In add/remove programs I have .NET Framework 3.5 installed and event does to it repair and iisreset, but I still have only to options in application pools management.

Any ideas?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 comes with .net 2.0 and .net 3.5. Remember even though you have .net framework 3.5 the CLR version is 2.0. There is no CLR v3.5. You can always host .net 3.5 related applications on the server where your web.config file will be referencing the necessary namespaces.

From the article [.NET Framework 3.5 Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx)

> The architecture of the .NET Framework
>   version 3.5 and 3.5 Service Pack 1
>   (SP1) builds upon the earlier versions
>   of the .NET Framework.
>
> An application uses the same
>   assemblies regardless of whether it
>   targets the .NET Framework version
>   2.0, 3.0, 3.5, or the Client Profile, and regardless of whether the
>   assemblies have been updated on a
>   user's computer. For example, an
>   application that uses Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF) and
>   targets the .NET Framework 3.0 uses
>   the same instance of the mscorlib
>   assembly as an application that uses
>   Windows Forms and targets the .NET
>   Framework 2.0.

Comment: Thank you for replay, I have read the article, but I still didn't understood what I shoult to do for nor to receive Error:
"Linq is not in the System namespace"?

Comment: you will need System.Core reference

Comment: using System.Core?

Comment: check this out http://forums.asp.net/t/1264863.aspx

Comment: corrected.. thanx